# How can I create lots of sub-domains each one with its own IP address?

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have an application that has a lot of worker servers, and the servers number is increasing with time, I want to assign a sub-domain for each one of these servers, for example: `srv1.domain.com` ... `srv100.domain.com`, my main goal is to serve files from them.

Beside creating an `A` DNS record for each one of these servers, is there a better way to do this ?

I checked the DNS records for a domain that has a similar setup, I've found that the root domain doesn't have any `A` records for the sub-domains, but the sub-domains have, for example:

Using `dig`:

`$ dig rootdomain.com ANY`

It showed the `NS` records without any `A` records at all for the sub-domains, but

`$ dig srv1.sub.rootdomain.com ANY`

Showed an `A` record pointing to the server, how is that possible ? and how can I have a similar setup ?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be on the right path. If you intend to give each server an IP address, then you will need to create an A record for each server/sub-domain.

Comment: What if the number increases a lot ? isn't there a limit for the records ?

Comment: @Peter Only in regard to the number of IP addresses you have assigned. Otherwise, there is no limit. Case in point: subscriber lines, telecos that assign a sub-domain name per IP address that a user will use. Large scale DSL installations, for example, will use a single IP address and assigned sub-domain to identify the connection.